# MapDB fixed structure of key and value

Tags: java, mapdb

I would like to store a couple billion key,value pairs in MapDB.  I have specific requirements:

key = long (8 bytes)
value = maximum 5 entries of (UUID + from-date + to-date), so 5 * 32 bytes = 160

Requirement is to have single threaded app: load by key, and change one of the dates in the entries.  The size of the value will not change.

I wonder what the most efficient setup is to do gets and puts.  Do I gain performance by pre-allocating a byte array of 160 and use that as the value?  Or doesn't it matter and just use a byte array flexible in size?

Currently I have

```
       DB db = DBMaker
            .newFileDB(dbFile)
            .asyncWriteEnable()
            .asyncWriteFlushDelay(100)
            .transactionDisable()
            .make();
```

Pump:

```
       BTreeKeySerializer keySerializer = BTreeKeySerializer.ZERO_OR_POSITIVE_LONG;
       Map<Long, Item> map = db.createTreeMap("map")
            .pumpSource(source)
            .keySerializer(keySerializer)
            .make();
```

where source is

```
Iterator<Fun.Tuple2<Long, byte[]>> source = new Iterator<Fun.Tuple2<Long, byte[]>>()
```

Loading

```
        Map<Long, byte[]> map = db.<Long, byte[]>getTreeMap("map");
```

After using the datapump to load the map with 20,000,000 items (performance degrades over time), the lookups are a bit disappointing:

200,000 lookups in 199,999 ms.  (about 1000 / second)

the lookup increases dramatically after running my test app a second time:

200,000 lookups in 7,597 ms.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance given the fixed size requirements of the keys/values?   Any options I can enable?

I used a TreeMap because it has a data pump.  Would performance increase significantly when using a HashMap?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

MapDB author here.

First use specialized key/value serializers. Something like:

```
db.createTreeMap("map").keySerializer(BTreeKeySerializer.STRING).makeOrGet();
```

Second you are experiencing performance bug in 1.0 branch. This was solved in 2.0, but that branch is not stable yet.